# Add a dash box in the flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

Those are the three flowcharts I want to draw, and there are some problems:

1. How to add the `Dashed Box` and `Cross` in the third picture.
2. I don't know how to add the rectangle `Bond worth P` in the first picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,calc,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    process/.style={
        text width=2.5cm, draw,
        minimum height=1.6cm,
        text centered,
        },
    process1/.style={
        text width=2.5cm, draw,
        minimum height=0.8cm,
        text centered,
        },
    description/.style={
        text centered,
        text width=10cm,
    },
    myarrow/.style={
        postaction={
            decorate, decoration={
                markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{Stealth};
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\singlespacing}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Default\\ protection\\ buyer};
    \node[process, right=10em of p1]  (p2) {Default\\ protection\\ seller};

    \draw[-Stealth, line width=1pt] ([yshift=-8ex, xshift=8ex]p2.west) -- node[description, above] {100} ([yshift=-8ex, xshift=-8ex]p1.east);
    \draw [-Stealth, line width=1pt]([yshift= 8ex,xshift=0.5cm]$(p1)$) --node[midway] (Rect){}([yshift=8ex,xshift=-.5cm]$(p2)$);
    \draw[fill=white] ($(Rect)+(-1.5,-0.7)$)rectangle($(Rect)+(1.5,0.7)$) node[midway] (Text){};
    \node at (Text) {\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering
             Bond\\ worth P
          \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Asset Swap\\ Seller};
    \node[process, right=8em of p1]  (p2) {Asset Swap\\ Buyer};
    \node[process1, right=4em of p2]  (p3) {Bond};

    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=2ex]p1.east) -- node[description, above] {C} ([yshift=2ex]p2.west);
    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=-2ex]p2.west) -- node[description, below] {LIBOR + S} ([yshift=-2ex]p1.east);
    \draw[-Stealth] (p3.west) -- node[description, below] {C} (p2.east);
    \draw[dashed] ($(p1)+(-1.8,-1)$)rectangle($(p2)+(1.8,1)$);
    \draw[ultra thick] ($(p3)+(-1.7,-0.8)$)--($(p3)+(1.7,0.8)$);
    \draw[ultra thick] ($(p3)+(-1.7,0.8)$)--($(p3)+(1.7,-0.8)$);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this:

[image]

**edit:**
in comparison to your code i made the following changes, which make code more clear, easy to understand and concise:

- to `tikzlibrary` are added libraries `fit`, `positioning`, `quotes`, `shapes.misc` and removed not used in this images
- used is decent `tikz` syntax
- used are document class `article` in combination with package `geometry` instead of `ctexart`. this doesn't influence on image design and usability.
- defined is new, universal style for all boxes in flowchart which enable automatic text breaking into more lines, has shadow around node and has option for determining node width (by this all used mini pages become superfluous)
- for **dashed frame** around " and "Asset Swap Buyer" i define new node style `fbox` (as frame box), which is positioned by use of tikz library `fit`
- for cross out a node is defined new box style using library `shapes.misc`
- for nodes positioning are used library `positioning`, for lines between nodes are determined auxiliary coordinates (`c`, `c1` and `c2`), which simplify drawing nodes.
- for labels on lines is used library `quotes`
- i didnt bother with line spacing in your document. your solution will work with this code without any problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, fit, positioning, quotes,
                shadows, shapes.geometric, shapes.misc}

\tikzset{FlowChart/.style =
{
  box/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=white,
               text width=##1, minimum height=8mm, align=center,
               inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
               drop shadow={shadow xshift=2mm, shadow yshift=-2mm}
               },
box/.default = 22mm,
 cbox/.style = {cross out=1m, draw, very thick,
                inner sep=3mm, node contents={}},
 fbox/.style = {rectangle, draw, densely dashed, inner sep=4mm},
   LA/.style = {semithick, -Triangle}
}
        }

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
some text
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 0mm and 8mm
                        ]
\node (p1) [box] {Asset Swap Seller};
\node (p2) [box=32mm, above right=of p1] {Bond\\ worth P};
\node (p3) [box, below right=of p2] {Asset Swap Buyer};
%
\draw [LA]  (p1 |- p2) -- (p2)
            (p2) -- (p2 -| p3);
%
\coordinate[below=4mm of p1.south] (c);
\draw [LA]  (p3.south |- c) to ["100"]  (c);
% fake node,
\node[right=38mm of p3.east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
some text
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 0mm and 8mm
                        ]
\node (p1) [box] {Asset Swap Seller};
\node (p2) [box, right=48mm of p1] {Asset Swap Buyer};
\node (p3) [box, right=16mm of p2] {Bond};
%
\node (p4) [fbox, fit=(p1) (p2)]  {};
%
\coordinate[above=2mm of p1.east] (c1);
\coordinate[below=2mm of p1.east] (c2);
\draw [LA]  (c1 -| p2.west) to ["C" '] (c1);
\draw [LA]  (c2) to ["LIBOR + C" '] (c2 -| p2.west);
%
\draw [LA,very thick]  (p3) to ["C" ']  (p2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
some text
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 0mm and 8mm
                        ]
\node (p1) [box] {Asset Swap Seller};
\node (p2) [box, right=48mm of p1] {Asset Swap Buyer};
\node (p3) [box, right=16mm of p2] {Bond};
%
\node (p4) [fbox, fit=(p1) (p2)]  {};
\node      [cbox, fit=(p3)];
%
\coordinate[above=2mm of p1.east] (c1);
\coordinate[below=2mm of p1.east] (c2);
\draw [LA]  (c1 -| p2.west) to ["C" '] (c1);
\draw [LA]  (c2) to ["LIBOR + C" '] (c2 -| p2.west);
%
\draw [LA,very thick]  (p3) to ["C" ']  (p2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX I used your updated method, but I don't how to modify this part of code `\draw[fill=white] ($(Rect)+(-1.5,-0.7)$)rectangle($(Rect)+(1.5,0.7)$) node[midway] (Text){};
    \node at (Text) {\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering
             Bond\\ worth P
          \end{minipage}};` two arrows seem has different length.

Comment: thanks, your answer is pretty good, but it seems much different from my previous code.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, which i haven't ...

Comment: @A.Oreo, of course, code is completely different, far more clean, simple  and concise :-).

Comment: @CarLaTeX just copy from previous question.

Comment: @CarLaTeX get it,  and how to solve the problem of different length?

Answer (score 5):

**Edited with the new style and added shadows:**

All you need is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\tikzset{
    process/.style={
        inner sep=0,
        text width=2.5cm, draw,
        minimum height=1.6cm,
        text centered,
        },
    process1/.style={
        text width=2.5cm, draw,
        minimum height=0.8cm,
        text centered,
        },
    description/.style={
        text centered,
        text width=10cm,
    },
    myarrow/.style={
        postaction={
            decorate, decoration={
                markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{Stealth};
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\singlespacing}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black!20!white] ($(-1.25,-0.8)+(0.25,-0.2)$)rectangle($(1.25,0.8)+(0.25,-0.2)$);
    \node[process,fill=white](p1) at(0,0) {Default\\ protection\\ buyer};
    \fill[black!20!white] ($(7.25,-0.8)+(0.25,-0.2)$)rectangle($(9.75,0.8)+(0.25,-0.2)$);
    \node[process, right=6cm of p1,fill=white]  (p2) {Default\\ protection\\ seller};

    \fill[black!20!white] ($(2.95,0.4)+(0.25,-0.2)$)rectangle($(5.5,2.05)+(0.25,-0.2)$);
    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=8ex, xshift=-7ex]p1.east) -- node[process,fill=white] {90 basis points per year} ([yshift=8ex, xshift=7ex]p2.west);
    \draw[-Stealth, line width=1pt] ([yshift=-8ex, xshift=7ex]p2.west) -- node[description, above] {100} ([yshift=-8ex, xshift=-7ex]p1.east);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black!20!white] ($(-1.25,-0.8)+(0.25,-0.2)$)rectangle($(1.25,0.8)+(0.25,-0.2)$);
    \node[process,fill=white] (p1) at (0,0) {Asset Swap\\ Seller};
    \fill[black!20!white] ($(4,-0.8)+(0.25,-0.2)$)rectangle($(6.6,0.8)+(0.25,-0.2)$);
    \node[process, right=8em of p1,fill=white]  (p2) {Asset Swap\\ Buyer};
    \fill[black!20!white] ($(8,-0.4)+(0.25,-0.2)$)rectangle($(10.7,0.4)+(0.25,-0.2)$);
    \node[process1, right=4em of p2,fill=white]  (p3) {Bond};

    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=2ex]p1.east) -- node[description, above] {C} ([yshift=2ex]p2.west);
    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=-2ex]p2.west) -- node[description, below] {LIBOR + S} ([yshift=-2ex]p1.east);
    \draw[-Stealth] (p3.west) -- node[description, below] {C} (p2.east);
    \draw[dashed] ($(p1.south west)-(1,0.5)$)rectangle($(p2.north east)+(1,0.5)$);
    \draw[ultra thick] ($(p3)-(1.2,-0.7)$)--($(p3)+(1.2,-0.7)$);
    \draw[ultra thick] ($(p3)-(1.2,0.7)$)--($(p3)+(1.2,0.7)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The new stuff from the previous is that for the rectangle we give two opposite corners and the word rectangle between them. (I filled it white to delete the previous part of the arrow that was there). Also, dashed option works for rectangle as for lines. Finally adding cordinates to a point gives as the opportunity to draw lines or shapes by using known coordinates.

For the shadows it would be easier to not have a code with starting point and shifts are not really helping (right=of and right of are not really appropriate for such cases)

Output:

[image]

Comment: I update code, but there are some problem in`\draw [-Stealth, line width=1pt]([yshift= 8ex,xshift=0.5cm]$(p1)$) --node[midway] (Rect){}([yshift=8ex,xshift=-.5cm]$(p2)$);
    \draw[fill=white] ($(Rect)+(-1.5,-0.7)$)rectangle($(Rect)+(1.5,0.7)$) node[midway] (Text){};
    \node at (Text) {\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering` two arrows  may have some difference in length, how to set the length here?

Comment: @A.Oreo... have you resolved your problem? I didn't understood what you want. Please edit your question to add an update with your current problem