# Flowchart with comments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw this on Tex. Could you give me a hand ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, fit, positioning, quotes,
                shadows, shapes.geometric, shapes.misc}

\tikzset{FlowChart/.style =
{
  box/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=white,
               text width=##1, minimum height=8mm, align=center,
               inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
               drop shadow={shadow xshift=2mm, shadow yshift=-2mm}
               },
box/.default = 22mm,
 cbox/.style = {cross out=1m, draw, very thick,
                inner sep=3mm, node contents={}},
 fbox/.style = {rectangle, draw, densely dashed, inner sep=4mm},
   LA/.style = {semithick, -Triangle}
}
        }

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
some text
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 0mm and 8mm
                        ]
\node (p1) [box] {Asset Swap Seller};
\node (p2) [box=32mm, above right=of p1] {Bond\\ worth P};
\node (p3) [box, below right=of p2] {Asset Swap Buyer};
%
\draw [LA]  (p1 |- p2) -- (p2)
            (p2) -- (p2 -| p3);
%
\coordinate[below=4mm of p1.south] (c);
\draw [LA]  (p3.south |- c) to ["100"]  (c);
% fake node,
\node[right=38mm of p3.east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
some text
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 0mm and 8mm
                        ]
\node (p1) [box] {Asset Swap Seller};
\node (p2) [box, right=48mm of p1] {Asset Swap Buyer};
\node (p3) [box, right=16mm of p2] {Bond};
%
\node (p4) [fbox, fit=(p1) (p2)]  {};
%
\coordinate[above=2mm of p1.east] (c1);
\coordinate[below=2mm of p1.east] (c2);
\draw [LA]  (c1 -| p2.west) to ["C" '] (c1);
\draw [LA]  (c2) to ["LIBOR + C" '] (c2 -| p2.west);
%
\draw [LA,very thick]  (p3) to ["C" ']  (p2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
some text
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 0mm and 8mm
                        ]
\node (p1) [box] {Asset Swap Seller};
\node (p2) [box, right=48mm of p1] {Asset Swap Buyer};
\node (p3) [box, right=16mm of p2] {Bond};
%
\node (p4) [fbox, fit=(p1) (p2)]  {};
\node      [cbox, fit=(p3)];
%
\coordinate[above=2mm of p1.east] (c1);
\coordinate[below=2mm of p1.east] (c2);
\draw [LA]  (c1 -| p2.west) to ["C" '] (c1);
\draw [LA]  (c2) to ["LIBOR + C" '] (c2 -| p2.west);
%
\draw [LA,very thick]  (p3) to ["C" ']  (p2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is the code in your question (that is by the way quite similar/identical to the one [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396395/134144)) related to the screenshot of the desired output you showed?

Comment: Yes. I got it from there just to put a mwe.

Comment: But as far as I can see, the example code is not at all related to teh image you would like to have or do I overlook something? Did you try to make any adjustments?

Comment: I got stuck at the outer boxes and then I dropped the mic.

Comment: Probably helpful regarding the boxes around parts of the flowchart:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204783/134144 and regarding the curly brace: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20885/134144

Comment: @leandriis thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of this is difficult, and [leaandris has already provided you with useful links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507600/flowchart-with-comments#comment1282665_507600). You would learn much more if you tried them out yourself. (I did not have the patience to type in all the texts.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries,
standard/.style={draw=blue!70,minimum height=2em,minimum
width=#1,text=blue},
partitioned/.style={standard=#1,path picture={
\path(path picture bounding box.south west)
-- (path picture bounding box.south east) foreach \XX [count=\YY] 
in {0.1,0.2,...,0.6,0.9} {coordinate[pos=\XX] (aux\YY)};
\draw foreach \YY in {1,...,7} {(aux\YY) -- 
(aux\YY|-path picture bounding box.north)};
\draw[dotted,thick,shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex] (path picture bounding box.west-|aux6) 
-- (path picture bounding box.west-|aux7);}},
marrow/.style={sloped,minimum height=1.4cm,minimum width=1.2cm,
   single arrow, single arrow head extend=.125cm, allow upside down,
   top color=blue!30,bottom color=blue!70,scale=0.4}]
   \node[standard=8em] (T1) {Training Set}; 
   \node[standard=5em,right=0pt of T1] (T2) {Test Set}; 
   \node[above left=1.5ex of T1.north west,above right] (L1) 
   {\underline{Step 1: blablablablablablablablabla}};
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=pft]
    \node[below=6em of T1,partitioned=8em] (T3){};
    \node[right=1ex of T3,blue] (T4) {Training Set};
    \node[above=1.5ex of T3.north west,above right] (L2a) 
     {\underline{(i) blablablablablablablablabla}};
    \node[below=4em of T3.south west,above right] (L2b) 
     {\underline{(ii) blablablablablablablablabla}};
    \draw[very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=0.5ex}] (T3.south west) -- (T3.south east)
    node[midway,below=1ex] {$k$ parts};
    \draw[very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=0.5ex}] 
    (L2a.north west) -- (L2b.south west)
    node[midway,left=1ex,align=left] {\underline{Step 2:}\\
    \underline{$k$ fold cross}\\ \underline{validation}};
    \path (T3.-20) coordinate(aux)  -- (L2b.north-|aux) node[pos=0.6,marrow]{};
    \node[standard=8em,below=8em of aux] (T5) {Training Set};
    \node[above=1ex of T5] (L3) 
    {\underline{Step 3: blablablablablablablablabla}};
    \node[right=1em of T5,text width=4.5cm,font=\small\sffamily] {Note: use the configuration of the
    tuning parameters with the lowest cv.error};
    \path (L2b.south-|aux) -- (L3.north) node[midway,marrow]{};
    \node[standard=8em,below=4em of T5] (T6) {Test Set};
    \node[above=1ex of T6] (L4) 
    {\underline{Step 4: blablablablablablablablabla}};
    \path (T5.south) -- (L4.north) node[midway,marrow]{};
   \end{scope}
   \draw[red] ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=-1ex]pft.south west) rectangle 
   ([xshift=1ex,yshift=1ex]pft.north east);
   \node[above=0.3ex of pft] (Use){Use the following blablablablablablablablabla};
   \path (pft.north|-T1.south) -- (pft.north|-Use.north) node[midway,marrow]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cat! Thank you very much. It might be easy for you but, for me, it takes a lot of time (trial & error) and I end up getting the wrong answer. Although each time I try I get closer to a better result, meaning, better at tikZ.

Comment: Could you add the note part that says “Note: use the configuration of the tuning parameters with the lowest cv.error”

Comment: @Delan I added it. It is `\node[right=1em of T5,text width=4.5cm,font=\small\sffamily] {Note: use the configuration of the
    tuning parameters with the lowest cv.error};`. (The code was written in such a way that the box grows accordingly, this is the purpose of `local bounding box`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much!

Comment: I just realized that the first arrow at the top is coming out from Test Set and it actually has to come out from Training Set

Comment: @Delan Replace the very last `\path` command by `\path (T1.south) -- (T1.south|-Use.north) node[midway,marrow]{};`.